# Redirect beta to www apart from certain IP in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a beta server setup at `beta.domain.com` which is all working very nicely for testing purposes. However as it is a complete mirror of my life site it would accept a sale to a user as well as let the search engines spider it, so what I would want to do is limit beta to certain IPs (home and office) and all other people trying to visit it would be redirected to `www.domain.com`

My host for this site runs nginx and is heavily customised and I am rather locked out of what I would usually expect, however in their support docs they tell me how to redirect from www.domain.com to domain.com. They also say:

> Subdomains will inherit the Nginx rewrite and configuration rules from
>   the top-level domain. If you need to make specific rules for a
>   subdomain, you can use conditional statements for the $host

**Host example to redirect www.domain.com to domain.com**

```
set $redirect "0";
if ($host ~* "^(.+)\.domain\.com$") { set $cursubdomain $1; }
if ($host != www.$server_name)       { set $redirect "go"; }
if ($cursubdomain = "")              { set $redirect "go${redirect}"; }
if (!-d $root_dir/$cursubdomain)     { set $redirect "go${redirect}"; }
if ($redirect = "gogo") {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $my_http://www.$host$1 permanent;
}
```

I was thinking looking at the above this might be good for the redirect

```
if ($host ~* "beta\.domain\.com$") { 
  set $redirect "1";
}

if ($redirect = "1") {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $my_http://www.$host$1 permanent;
}
```

If that is indeed the right way to do it, not too sure about the best way to do the IP check, something like

```
if ($remote_addr != 127.0.0.1) {
  set $remoteredirect "1";
}

if($remoteredirect = "1") {
   if ($redirect = "1") {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ $my_http://www.$host$1 permanent;
   }
}
```

Is this the best way to go about this, or am I killing myself in performance or would it even work!

Comment: To do this right, you really need to use `geo`, but that must be placed outside the `server` block, and it sounds like you don't have that level of control over the server?

Comment: No, doesn't look like I do. I maybe should see if they can set me up a new server block to run my beta site on, then I will have a separate config file to do my redirects in